# How to save selected option(dropdown box) in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, select, ionic-framework

I want to save selected color value from dd box into $scope.color.

Index.html:

```
<label class="item item-select" name="selectName">
<span class="input-label">What is your favourite colour?</span>
<select id="colorid">
    <option ng-repeat="x in colorList"{{x}}</option>
</select>
</label>
```

controller.js:

```
var colorCtrl = function($scope){
$scope.color = "";
$scope.colorList =["red","blue","yellow"];
console.info("color is "+$scope.color);  
}
```

Comment: please explain your need in detail

Comment: I want to display selected color name on console.

Answer (score 0):

For binding value, use `ng-model`:

```
<select id="colorid" ng-model="color">...
```

for trigger event, use `ng-change` (calls $scope.onChange() ):

```
<select id="colorid" ng-model="color" ng-change="onChange()">...
```

And be careful to your options format! (it is the **value** which is binded, not the **content**!)

Full code:

```
<label class="item item-select" name="selectName">
                <span class="input-label">What is your favourite colour?</span>
              <select id="colorid" ng-model="color" ng-change="onChange()">
                <option ng-repeat="x in colorList" value="{{x}}">{{x}}</option>
              </select>
            </label>
```

And JS:

```
var colorCtrl = function($scope)
{
        $scope.color = "";
        $scope.colorList =["red","blue","yellow"

          ];
        $scope.onChange = function()
        {
            //trigerred on color change
             console.info("color is "+$scope.color);  
        }

}
```

Comment: This solution does not work. Need to pass color in onChange() .
ng-change = "onChange()"

Comment: You have color in ̀ `$scope.color`, normally... but if you want to pass the parameter in you function: `ng-change="onChange(this.value)"` and then `$scope.onChange = function(color)`

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a syntax error in your code.

In you want to take input from the DOM you have to tell angular which variable to store the input in.

This is done via the ng-model directive. 
As given in the documentation.

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form
>   control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is
>   created and exposed by this directive.
>
> ngModel is responsible for:
>
> Binding the view into the model, which other directives such as input,
>   textarea or select require.
>   Providing validation behavior (i.e.
>   required, number, email, url).

So, if I want to take input I will initialise the input element as,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="val" />
```

Via this, I have initialised a variable "val" on the scope (The Model) and I have told angular, whatever input is entered into the input element will be bound to that variable.

```
<label class="item item-select" name="selectName">
      <span class="input-label">What is your favourite colour?</span>
          <select id="colorid" ng-model="color">
            <option ng-repeat="x in colorList">{{x}}</option>
          </select>
</label>
```

Please check this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzoDo0EA7VgoJXPdxU4L?p=preview).

Comment: I had tried with ng-model where I was binding $scope.color with ng-model ="color". It did not work. I guess ng-change directive is what I was looking for.

Comment: Please check the link, it's a working example using the ng-model directive.
And please provide the code where it isn;t working using ng-model.

Answer (score 0):

You aleady got many answers here.Just for add on i will suggest you to do this way:

```
<select style="background:{{color}}" ng-model='color' ng-options='color as color for color in colorList' ng-change='selectionChanged(color)'>
</select>
```

or  you can also try with

```
 <select  ng-model='color'  ng-change='selectionChanged(color)'>
<options style="background:{{color}}" ng-repeat="color as color for color in colorList" value={{color}}>
{{color}}</options>
    </select>
```